# Кого называли чухонцами?

Tags: этимология

И еще вопрос о старом языке. Кого раньше называли чухонцами: финнов или эстонцев? И откуда вообще пошло это не слишком благозвучное слово?

Comment: Однажды А.Ф.Кони по ошибке сгребли в участок. " Наконец, уже под утро, совершенно
сонный околоточный позвал его к
столу, взял новый листок бумаги и,
пуская из ноздрей струи дыма, начал
допрос.
- Фамилия?
- Кони.
- Чухна?
- Нет, русский.
- Врешь. Ну, да ладно. Там разберут.
Звание? Чем занимаешься?
- Прокурор Санкт-Петербургского
окружного суда.
Немая сцена... "Еффехт", как говорит
один из персонажей Островского."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всех финно-угров. Т.е. и финнов, и эстонцев, и ижорцев и многие другие ныне исчезнувшие племена, бытовавшие когда-то в новогородских землях.  "Чухна" (Чудь) не было официальным названием какой-то национальности, поэтому границы применимости установить четко нельзя.
По Фасмеру образовано от "чудь" (того же значения) с помощью некогда продуктивного суффикса -"хн(о)", морфосемантика которого мне лично не совсем понятна: то ли уничижительного, то ли собирательного...

Answer (score 2):

Могу предположить, что "чухонцы" появились от слова "чудь", обозначавшее финно-угорские племена. Учитывая, что все финно-угры для новгородцев были на одно лицо и диалекты языка они не могли различить, то скорее всего чудью могли называть и эстов (будущих эстонцев), и финнов (которые были "сумью", сравни с "Суоми", самоназванием финнов).

Поэтому сказать какие именно точно финно-угорские народности назывались чухонцами не представляется возможным. Это собирательный термин, которым могли называться любые финно-угорские племена.

Comment: Вообще-то, чудью белоглазой называли мифический народ, живущий в пещерах, насколько мне известно.

Comment: >Вообще-то, чудью белоглазой называли мифический народ, живущий в пещерах, насколько мне известно.

Было такое, но именно **белоглазой**. 
По поводу пещер - я тоже не очень понимаю, в новгородских землях пещер нет. Это на Урале, видимо. Там тоже было порядочно финно-угорских народов, особенно на севере.